# Criteria for $\epsilon$-Density

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, approximation-theory, metric-spaces, function-spaces

Let $Y$ be a compact, separable metric space and $X=C(Y)$ Banach space.  There are many criteria for a linear subspace $Z\subseteq X$ to be dense; notably the [Stone-Weierstraß](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) theorem.

Are there theorems giving conditions on non-linear subsets $Z$ of $X$ to be [ε-dense?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651090/whats-the-difference-between-%CE%B5-dense-and-dense)  Particularly, if I know that

- $Z$ comprises *"partial sums"* of at-most $N$ elements; *i.e.*,
  $$
  Z=\left\{
  k+\sum_{i=0}^N k_iy_i:\, y_i \in \tilde{Y}, k,k_i \in \mathbb{R}
  \right\},
  $$
  for some positive integer $N>0$ and some subset $\tilde{Y}\subseteq Z\subseteq C(Y)$,
- $\operatorname{span}(Z)$ is dense in $X$?

Comment: Do you mean that *Z is comprised of "partial sums"*?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your set $Z$ is $\epsilon$-dense, then it is also dense!  This is in fact so for every normed space $X$, and for every  subset $Z\subseteq X$ which is positively homogeneous in the sense that $\alpha Z = Z$, for every scalar $\alpha>0$.  The reason is as follows, for any point $x$ in $X$, and any $\alpha>0$, one has that
  $$
  d(\alpha x,Z) = d(\alpha x,\alpha Z) = \alpha \,d(x,Z),
  $$
  where $d$ is the distance function.

Thus, if $Z$ is $\epsilon$-dense, one has for every $x$ in $X$, and every natural number $n>0$,  that
  $$
  d(x,Z) = (1/n)\,d(nx,Z) \leq (1/n)\varepsilon,
  $$
  from where you deduce that $d(x,Z)=0$

Comment: Nice!  This was subtle but very interesting!  Thank you.